# How to make navigator.share work for Facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, progressive-web-apps

I am using the Native Share API to share text from my PWA with the phone's installed applications, as described here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share

```
navigator.share({ text:"My shared text" });
```

This opens the phone's list of installed apps and lets me choose one of them, and then inserts the text. For example for Twitter it creates a new tweet with the text. Works fine for all apps except Facebook, where it creates a new post, but leaves out the text. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Because Facebook doesn't allow you to prefill text. The user has to type the text they post.

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for this?

Comment: @ShridharPatil No I didn't find any solution.

Comment: Wordle does it - i can't work out how though!